# Code doesn't work, getting error: segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c

Can someone explain why this snippet of code doesn't work?
It is intended to duplicate a file, when I compile it I get segmentation fault(core dumped), I appreciate all the critics. Sorry if there are any typos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define MAXLEN 30

void copy(FILE *source,FILE *dest);    

int main(void)
{
       FILE *fs, *fa;                              // fs for source file, fa for copy

       char file_src[MAXLEN];                      // name of source file
       char file_app[MAXLEN];                      // name of copy file

       puts("File copy program\n\n");
       puts("Enter name of source file:");
       gets(file_src);                             // get the file name
       if(fs=fopen(file_src,"r")==NULL)           // error checking
       {
             fprintf(stderr,"Cant open %s.\n",file_src);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       if(setvbuf(fs,NULL,_IOFBF,BUFSIZE)!=0)   //  set the buffer for fs
        {
             fprintf(stderr,"Cant create input buffer.\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       puts("Now enter the copy name file:");
       gets(file_app);                             // get file name

       if(fa=fopen(file_app,"w")==NULL)            // error checking
       {
             fprintf(stderr,"Cant open %s.\n",file_app);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       if(setvbuf(fa,NULL,_IOFBF,BUFSIZE)!=0)      // set up buffer for fa
       {
             fprintf(stderr,"Cant create output buffer.\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       copy(fs,fa);                              // copy file fs to fa

       if(ferror(fs)!=0)
       {
             fprintf(stderr,"Error in reading file\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       if(ferror(fa)!=0)
       {
             fprintf(stderr,"Error in writing file\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       puts("Done");
       return 0;
}

void copy(FILE *source,FILE *dest)
{
       size_t bytes=0; 
       static char temp[BUFSIZE];

       while(bytes=fread(temp,sizeof(char),BUFSIZE,source) > 0)   
            fwrite(temp,sizeof(char),bytes,dest);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
if(fs=fopen(file_src,"r")==NULL)
```

is wrong. It is probably ending up assigning `fs` to `NULL`, when the open  *succeeds*, which is then *not* checked and thus causes the fault when the `NULL` is used in later calls.

It must be

```
if((fs = fopen(file_src, "r")) == NULL)
```

due to how operator priority works in C.

By the way, a generic copying program like this should open the files in binary mode.

Comment: Or simply just `if (!(fs = fopen(file_src, "r")))` because `NULL`evaluates to `false` and everything else to `true` anyway.

Comment: @Tibor Yes, of course, but I prefer explicit checks against `NULL` and prefer keeping implicit conversion to boolean to a minimum. It costs very little, and I think it makes the code easier to read and reason about. Especially for a beginner, like here.

Comment: thanks, when I fixed it to if((fs=fopen(file_src,"rb"))==NULL) and the if((fa=fopen(file_app,"wb"))==NULL) I get no errors in compile just warnings about the gets the program runs no problem and I wanted to copy this source file to the copy.txt file and the program just created this document but it didnt output any data to that text. whats wrong

Comment: also I have a few questions
1. Is it better to read and write text files in binary mode?
2. If I use this program just for text files could I  istead of fread and fwrite use fgetc and fputc or fprintf and fscanf ?

Comment: @user3717347 Please don't post follow-up questions as comments, Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. Post new question(s).